# How to find symmetrical words in string?

Tags: string, pascal, symmetric

I've been trying to make this work for a while now.
I need to make a program for school project that takes a string and counts symmetrical words inside it.

There are supposed to be sentences inside, but anything helps. I can't seem to get it to work no matter what approach I try. Could you help me out?

EDIT: my current code

```
program rocnik;
var text:string;
    word,drow:string[10];
    i,j,k,p1:integer;
    space,sym:boolean;

begin
     p1:=0;
     write('Enter text: ');readln(text);
     if text<>'' then
     begin
          for i:=1 to length(text) do
          begin
               k:=0;
               if space then
               begin
                    j:=0;
                    space:=false;
               end;
               sym:=true;
               if text[i]<>' ' then
               begin
                    j:=j+1;
                    word[j]:=text[i];
               end
               else space:=true;
               if space then
               begin
                    space:=false;
                    for j:=1 to length(word) do
                    begin
                         k:=k+1;
                         drow[k]:=word[j];
                         if drow[k]<>word[j] then sym:=false;
                    end;
               end;
               if space and sym then p1:=p1+1;
          end;
     end
     else writeln('You didnt enter any text');
     writeln('there are ',p1,' symmetrical words in text');
     readln;
end.
```

Comment: Help is doubtful if you do not provide any code from your attempt.

Comment: Sorry about that, added my current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to do everything at once! Programming is often an exercise in breaking a big problem down into multiple easier problems.

You really only need to check for a symmetrical word at the end of each word. I suggest having a string that represents the current word. As you encounter each character in the input, see if it is a space. If it is not a space, append that character to a `currentWord` string variable.

Every time you encounter a space, you should check `currentWord` for symmetry, then clear the `currentWord` variable.

Your code tries to separately keep track of the length of the word. This is asking for bugs. You can ask the string for its current length, using the `length` function.

So your code should boil down to this:

*Note that this is pseudo-Pascal - I am trying not to hand you a copy-paste answer so you will learn*

```
currentWord := ''
for each character do
begin
    if this character is not a space then
        add the character to the currentWord
    else
        if wordIsSymmetrical(currentWord) then
            print word or add to count as needed
        end
        currentWord := ''
    end
end
if currentWord <> '' then
    if wordIsSymmetrical(currentWord) then
        print word or add to count as needed
    end
end
```

...and add a function called `wordIsSymmetrical` which only checks the string parameter that we pass to it.

Note that at the end you may have a word without encountering a space. Here again you can use `wordIsSymmetrical` to check .

Does that seem easier to do?

Comment: Added handling of case of a word at the end of the input with no space after it.

Comment: This helped me tremendously. I really appreciate you taking your time to write this down. Yes, this is much easier. Changed it a bit because it's going to be sentences, not just words and one character is not what I'm looking for. Really thank you once again. And once again sorry for not adding my code right away.

Comment: This pseudo-code does not look for one character, it only looks one character at a time, looping through the entire sentence. It assumes that words are separated by spaces, so each time you encounter one, that is when you check if the word you assembled from the previous single characters is symmetrical (whatever that may be - anagram?).